# How to get only COMx in Serial.Tools.List (Python)?

Tags: python, serial-port

I created a program, which sorts all connected Devices (Serials). I only want the List to get COMx Ports instead of their description.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
List1 = []
for  port in sorted(ports):
        List1.append(port)

print(*List1)
```

It always shows the description too, and i don't know what to do?
Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Any Ideas?
*I also read the pyserial documentation and tried to divide results into port, desc, hwid, didn't work...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you will be able to list only the COM port names with one of the following:

```
List1.append(port.name)
```

or

```
List1.append(port.device)
```

If you stick to the string named COMx, you can change comports() to:

```
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.grep("COM[1-9][0-9]*")
```

[serial.tools.list_ports](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.list_ports)
[classserial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo)

> - device
>   Full device name/path, e.g. /dev/ttyUSB0. This is also the information returned as first element when accessed by index.
> - name
>   Short device name, e.g. ttyUSB0.